# How can I replace an instance variable with another one conditionally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I am assigning values to an instance variable of a class. The scenario is that I need to call a function at least three times, and each call requires an answer to be stored in another instance variable.

Keep in mind that 'RuboCop' may throw errors.

The class named Major is as follows.

```rb
class Major

  attr_accessor :max_temp, :min_temp, :max_humid, :max_t_day, 
  :min_temp_day, :max_humid_day

  def initialize
    @max_temp = -440
    @min_temp = 1000
    @max_humid = -500
    @max_t_day = 'fahad'
    @min_temp_day = 'fahad'
    @max_humid_day = 'fahad'
  end

  def day_wise_results
    _arg, year, path, _month = ARGV
    arr = Dir.entries(path).select { |x| x.include?(year) }
    # max_temp_day, min_temp_day, max_humid_day = ''

    arr.each do |yc|
      collection = file_collection("#{ path }/#{ yc }")
      collection.shift

      temperature_with_day(collection, 1, true, '>')
      temperature_with_day_min(collection, 3, false, '<')
      temperature_with_day_humid(collection, 7, true, '>')
end
```

The functions have virtually identical code; however, the instance variables are different. Plus, I do not wish to have repeated code.

### Functions

```rb
def temperature_with_day(collection, col, is_max, operator)
  if separate_collections(collection, col, is_max).public_send(
    operator, @max_temp
  )
    @max_temp = separate_collections(collection, col,
    is_max)
  end
  collection.each do |row|
    @max_t_day = row[0] if row[col].to_i.eql?(@max_temp)
  end
end

def temperature_with_day_min(collection, col, is_max, operator)
  if separate_collections(collection, col, is_max).public_send(
    operator, @min_temp
  )
    @min_temp = separate_collections(collection, col,
    is_max)
  end
  collection.each do |row|
    @min_temp_day = row[0] if row[col].to_i.eql?(@min_temp)
  end
end

def temperature_with_day_humid(collection, col, is_max, 
operator)
  if separate_collections(collection, col, is_max).public_send(
    operator, @max_humid
  )
    @max_humid = separate_collections(collection, col,
    is_max)
  end
  collection.each do |row|
    @max_humid_day = row[0] if row[col].to_i.eql?(@max_humid)
  end
end
```

Evidently, the blocks of code are the same within those three functions, as above.

#### Is there a way to refactor the code to avoid repetition and use a single instance variable?

I would also like to refactor those functions using best practices and avoid 'RuboCop' from throwing errors.

Ultimately, each of those three instance variables should return some value.

Comment: What's the point of going through the same collection several times setting different instance variables? Can't it be done via a single iteration (especially taking into account that it seems this code touches a file system - that is a very slow beast). What I am trying to say is that instead of thinking about XY problem think in a wider context - how to refactor this logic (maybe including `separate_collections` method whose signature now smells quite a bit)

Comment: Regardless of the current structure: may I ask what the code is supposed to achieve? What kind of data do you have in your filesystem and what data are you trying to retrieve? I assume it's some min / max values but I'm not sure. Maybe you can give a small example with input and expected output / result.

Comment: It's supposed to read a file and display temperatures along with dates.

Comment: _"reading a file and displaying temperatures with dates"_ sounds simple. Like something you could write in 5-10 lines. Your code on the other hand is very complex with many indirections and multiple loops. Maybe you can give a little more explanation on why you're approaching it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use a hash instead, passing a symbol to indicate which value you want to use? Something like this, which adds the extra value as the first argument for the method, here called `type`.

```rb
  def initialize
    @temp = { max: -440, min: 1000, humid: -500 }
    @temp_day = { max: 'fahad', min: 'fahad', humid: 'fahad' }
  end

...

  def temperature_with_day(type, collection, col, is_max, operator)
    if separete_collections(collection, col, is_max).public_send(
      operator, @temp[type]
    )
      @temp[type] = separete_collections(collection, col, is_max)
    end
    collection.each do |row|
      @temp_day = row[0] if row[col].to_i.eql?(@temp[type])
    end
  end
```

If you still need separate methods to set and return the three values, you can add these explicitly instead of relying on the automatic accessors, something like this:

```rb
def max_temp=(value)
  @temp[:max] = value
end

def max_t_day
  return @temp_day[:max]
end
```

and so on.

(PS Your method `separete_collections` should probably be called `separate_collections`, I think - just a spelling mistake in "separ*a*te"!)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I don't know why I didn't thought about it and yeah it was spelling mistake. Sorry for that and Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some constant

```
SETTINGS = {
  max_temp: {
    col: 1,
    is_max: true,
    operator: :>
  },
  # ...
}
```

And then iterate over its

```
SETTINGS.each do |temp, opts|
  separete_collections = separete_collections(collection, opts[:col], opts[:is_max])

  if separete_collections.public_send(opts[:operator], public_send(temp))
    public_send("#{temp}=", separete_collections)
  end
end

if (row = collection.find { |row| row[col].to_i == @max_humid })
  public_send("#{temp}=", row[0])
end
```